# Using Cookies to Replicate Shopify Store for Affiliate Sales Tracking

Tags: cookies, shopify, session-cookies, replication, affiliate

**Good Day Everyone!**

So working on a project for a client who wants to track affiliate sales on Shopify. Problem is, they are not using any of the generic affiliate management solutions available in Shopify but their own in-house management system.

How could someone theoretically make replicated URLs so that whenever someone uses this URL to purchase anything on the store, it gets tracked to the affiliate and the order gets added to their sales and they can hence be paid out on it eventually.

I know that this would probably have something to do with cookies, affiliate and orders database and session tracking but I don't know how all these pieces fit together.

Any suggestions on how to implement this? If anyone already has done anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you are getting your info from, but when a browser lands on a Shopify page with a ref query parameter (let us say you assigned that to an affiliate code), that ref is saved along with the order created by that browser session. So if links are clicked with affiliate codes, Shopify just assigns them to the order. You get one per order. How is that complicated to deal with? What else are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Quite new to the entire platform and literally to this field as well. A question which I have is, as you said that the "ref" value gets assigned to the orders, how would I send this order information back to a database which lets say is to track the sales per ref ID.

Comment: Shopify, like any decent Internet platform, has Webhooks. So whenever an order is paid, it can be sent to anywhere on the Internet you care to send it. So you can send it to a simple script, tease out the ref, and do as you wish... Shopify has very in-depth documentation and is API supported, so a simple task like yours is cheap and easy to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm looking into and understanding it now.